# Laravel Group data by Month Query works with MySQL but Fails on PostgreSQL database

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm trying to group data by month for the current year. The query below works on MySQL database but gives an error when connected to PostgreSQL.

```
 $results = DB::table('visits')
        ->select(DB::raw('month(visitdate) month, count(*) data'))
        ->where('team_id', 2)
        ->whereYear('visitdate', now()->year)
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->get();
```

This error was generated:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "month" LINE 1: select month(visitdate) month, count(*) data from "visits" w... ^ (SQL: select month(visitdate) month, count(*) data from "visits" where "team_id" = 2 and extract(year from "visitdate") = 2021 group by "month")

I tried a similar query with Eloquent and got the same results.

The `visitdate` column stores the date in the format "2021-01-01"
I'm using laravel 8 with Breeze

Answer (score 0):

`month` is  a keyword.  You should choose something else instead, or put it in double quotes, or in this case just put `AS` in front of it.  Any of the three should work.